# Free jqGrid, don't send new index on addrow with inlineNav

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Just putting in a new grid, and everything seems to be working well, except for one thing.  Using basic inline, it is sending a new incorrect key value for the column I have set with `key: true`.  This is an auto-increment column in the database, so I just don't want to send any data for this column when ADDING, only for edit or delete is that required.

It is posting a parameter: `row_id => jqg3` for the new key column and messing up my server script.  So because adding the new row will auto-increment the `row_id` col, I don't need to send this.

**How do I stop the jqGrid from sending this (`row_id`) index column value when saving a new added row?**

free-jqgrid version is 4.14.0

```
$('#accts').jqGrid({
    url:'/phpAJAX/Master/master_grid_v1.php',
    editurl:'/phpAJAX/Master/master_grid_v1.php',
    height: 'auto',
    shrinkToFit: false,
    width: 'auto',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'POST',
    postData:{
        'arg1':'bol_acct'
    },
    colNames:[
        'row_id',
        'Customer',
        'Trucker',
        'Acct Num'
    ],
    colModel:[
        {name: 'row_id', hidden: true, key: true},
        {name:'Customer', align: "center", editable: true},
        {name: 'Trucker', align: "center"},
        {name: 'Acct_Num', align: "center"}
    ],
    sortname: 'Customer',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    caption: 'Bill of Lading Accounts',
    rowNum: 10000,
    pager:true
}).jqGrid('inlineNav', { 
    addParams: { 
        addRowParams: { extraparam: {'arg1':'bol_acct', 'oper':'add'} } 
    },
    editParams: {
        extraparam: {
            'arg1':'bol_acct', 'oper':'edit'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understand the problem. First of all I don't understand the meaning of hidden `row_id` column, because the rowid are saved in `id` attribute of every row (`<tr>`). The `oper` parameter will be set automatically to `add` or `edit` and thus you don't need to use different options for Add and Edit. Moreover I don't full understand the problem, which you report. The server can ignore the `id` in case of `oper=add`. The server code have to process Add and Edit requests in different way and just need to detect adding. One can do it by testing of `oper` parameter.

Comment: @Oleg yes i was debugging and set the `oper` param explicitly just to make sure, i guess that is redundant.  The pri_key col name is `row_id`, it is hidden because users don't care about it.  You're saying I don't need to include it at all in my jqGrid definition, is that right?

Comment: @Oleg i think the problem is with using the `key=true` for the row_id column.  Instead of sending the newly created id to the server using the name `id`, it was applying the name of my column `row_id`.  sorry about that.

Comment: One don't need to hold the copy of the same information in both `id` attribute and hidden`<td>` elements. The problem: you don't posted test data, which is response from `url`. The default format means the usage of `id` attribute in input data. Do you have to use `row_id` instead and to send `row_id` parameter instead of `id`? I'm not sure what you exactly need. One can use the corresponding jqGrid options.

Comment: Small remark, which is Independent on your main question. It's recommended to use JSON instead of XML. The options `height: 'auto', gridview: true, rowNum: 10000` can be removed in free jqGrid.

Comment: It's strange a little that you server side paging and sorting. Probably `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options would be what you need? You can return all the data to the grid and then hold, sort, filter the *local* data without communication with the  server. You can use small `rowNum` value for *local* paging.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for all the support.  Yes I agree I always use json for new scripts.  I was trying to make this grid backwards-compatible with a server script I have from a long time ago.  It was made to work with the form editor and the tables from that time also had primary keys which were entered by the user, so that is why the auto-generated `id` by the addRow function is giving me problems.  I'm not really sure why you want the jqGrid to generate its own `id` client side for new rows?

Comment: I think in this case I could use `loadonce` method like you're describing, but often the tables I work with have many rows, where loading all to the client is not efficient.  Issue here is with generating new rows.  So like a long time ago, users added their own primary key, so I needed that data on addRow, for this new grid, the PrimKey to auto-increment, so there is no input for PrimKey field.

Comment: The reason: there are only `editRow` method and `inlineNav` uses `addRow`, which generate new rowid and call `editRow`. The code of `editRow` send the content of `editable` columns *and* the content of the column, which has `key: true` to the server. In other words the reason on sending the information: the implementation of inline editing, which had no add row functionality initially and then the methods `inlineNav` and `addRow` was inserting, which uses `editRow`.

Comment: I'm not sure. Is your main problem solved now or not solved?

Comment: @Oleg Well not quite solved but I understand much better how jqGrid works.  The question was: how can I suppress the addRow function sending the ID value to the server? which I still don't know how to do.    There must be a generic way to edit the data which will be posted to the server, before it is posted?

Comment: `addRow` don't sent anything, but I can post an example how you configure inline editing option to prevent `editRow` to send `id` parameter if `oper` is `add`. I'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `serializeSaveData` callback of inline editing to modify the data, which will be send during inline editing. You can add `serializeSaveData` callback via

```
inlineEditing: {
    keys: true,
    extraparam: { arg1: "bol_acct" },
    serializeSaveData: function (postData) {
        var newPostData = $.extend(true, {}, postData);
        if (newPostData.oper === "add") {
            delete newPostData.id; // delete id parameter
        }
        return newPostData;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are the ultimate master of jqGrid!

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: Thanks! The `inlineEditing` is the options of jqGrid, which specify default options used by all inline editing methods inclusive `editRow`. Using such option you can use `inlineNav` without any additional parameters.

Comment: I see, great, yes I think using this will be more intuitive.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: In the same way you can use `cmTemplate: { align: "center" }` to specify defaults for `colModel`. You can delete `align: "center"` from all `colModel` or to use `align` with *another* value as `"center"`.

Comment: Just was looking around the web for some documentation for the available attributes for the `inlineEditing` parameter that you show here.  I want to initialize some autocompletes on the text boxes of the inline editor, I was expecting to find something like `beforeEdit` or `afterShowEdit`.  I was trying to look through the code as well but not seeing anything right off (https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.inlinedit.js) , so just asking.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: Look at the code of [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/), which uses `autocomplete` or/and `select2` inside of `dataInit`. It demonstrates additionally `createColumnIndex: true` property of `colModel` and `generateValue: true` property of `searchoptions`.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind: There are exist `beforeEditRow` and `oneditfunc` callbacks, which you can specify inside of `inlineEditing` too.